# How to get a better cardio benefit while running with a slower partner?

Tags: running, cardio

**Background:**
I have started running regularly with a partner who has a smaller stride than I do. Because there is only so much time in the day, my partner-running workouts have replaced my normal solo-running workout. The partner-running workouts are something I would like to continue with for multiple reasons beyond fitness goals.

**Problem:** My partner-running workouts last the same duration as my normal running workout (~50 mins), but because I am matching my running partner's pace, I am not getting my heart rate up into my target training zones as I would when running on my own.

**Question:** I have heard tips of exaggerating motion (e.g. high knees) to increase the effort / heart rate, but I do not want to regularly practice poor form (practice makes permanent) since this is something I have started doing every other day. Is there anything else I can do to improve my own cardio benefit while running with a partner that does not require poor form?

Comment: How about your partner biking while you run?

Comment: You could run circles around your partner :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider wearing a weight vest.  To maintain a given pace with additional weight, your power output must increase, so your cardiovascular efficiency must improve.  This has the unfortunate side-effect of increasing the stress on your body, especially your joints.

Comment: Maybe dragging a tire would hurt less, but both would be disagreeable to me if I was the partner :)

Answer (score 3):

You will be surprised the benefits you will gain by running slower - you'll be exclusively working your aerobic system. Unless these partner-runs are replacing any hard workouts (tempos, intervals, etc.), then you may end up doing yourself more good than you realise - on the basis that easy running provides a good base.

Answer (score 3):

Do what one of my running partners does with me. Run alongside me until you feel the need to "stretch it out" and then go sprint ahead for a bit. Then return back and run alongside. In some cases you can get close to running 1.5 times the distance (as logged by our fitness trackers).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try running backwards or sideways, as [this requires more energy](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1984.58.1.149).